# Is my regex catastrophically backtracking?

Tags: java, regex, recursive-backtracking

I use a regex to validate number formats.

```
[-+]?([0-90-9]+((\,([0-90-9]{2,}))*\,([0-90-9]{3}))*)?(\.[0-90-9]*)?
```

When I handled a large number of inputs for certain inputs it seems to loop infinitely .I read other answers regarding catastrophic backtracking .
But I am a regex newbie and need some help.
can you please provide any input that can make this regex catastrophically backtrack . Would be helpful for me to understand .Thanks .It can be a very long input too .
I am using Java Pattern and matcher objects.

Comment: `[0-90-9]` can be changed to `[0-9]`

Comment: What are the requirements for the pattern? `[0-90-9]` is certainly not the main problem here, but the nested quantifiers inside groups.

Comment: Thanks ,I noticed that , But I would really appreciate if someone can make this regex backtrack infinitely.In that case I can be sure thats the problem

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Find me an input which would break this regex ie cause it to loop infinitely

Comment: This has nothing to do with "infinite loop" _or_ "recursive backtracking"...

Comment: all of your capturing groups are optional , where using `?` or `*` and if you want to validate input, add `^...$` warapper @SainathS.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this regex is prone to catastrophic backtracking. Specifically, this segment:

```
((\,([0-9]{2,}))*\,([0-9]{3}))*
```

For reference, this has a structure of the form

```
((,d)*,d)*
```

which, simplified, is essentially `(d+)*`.

Strings like

```
1,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,11.
```

will therefore cause catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: That string ran fine :(

Comment: Note that this is only an issue in an anchored context, e.g. `.matches`

Comment: @SainathS.R Then make it longer.

Comment: @SebastianProske Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Rawing I made it very long ,still terminated in reasonable time

Comment: @SainathS.R Make sure it's anchored: `^[-+]?([0-90-9]+((\,([0-90-9]{2,}))*\,([0-90-9]{3}))*)?(\.[0-90-9]*)?$`

Answer (score 0):

To validate your input string use this one:

```
^[-+]?(\d+((\,(\d{2,}))*\,(\d{3}))*)?(\.\d*)?$
```

As I've wrote in comments:

> all of your capturing groups are optional , where using `?` or `*` and if you want to validate input, add `^...$` wrapper

Have a look at right side bar of https://regex101.com/r/eM7OFj/1 titled by **MATCH INFORMATION**

Comment: Thank you , I know the pattern can be changed to something better but I would like to know any sample input which can cause this pattern to run indefinitely .

Comment: Your pattern runs for each Character in the input text. Note to use ^ $

Comment: `Test your regex` has 16 matched null string @SainathS.R